# What LS00 is a TI 89D3EEK?

Tags: datasheet

I am trying to fix a robot control unit where the L6203 driver was burned / cracked. Replacing the L6203 did not make the motor run, so I am trying to trace backwards on the board. I expect the LS00 in the picture to be controlling the L6203, but I cannot find any data on a 89D3EEK. Could someone point me to a datasheet?[image]

Comment: This most likely is a **74**LS00. 89D3 is most likely a timecode (year 1989, week "D3") and EEK a factory/line code.

Answer (score 1):

LS00 is the SOIC package variant of TI's SN7400D, in other words, a 7400 chip.

See the TI datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7400.pdf), page 2.

It's just a set of NAND gates. The 89D3EEKG4 is really probably just a production counter/ID thing and has no functional significance, at all.

Hence, test the NAND gates inside. If the IC is broken, get the identical TI chip again, or just susbtitute with any 7400 that has compatible voltage levels.

Comment: 7400D is pin-for-pin compatible, but 7400LS00D is a more proper replacement, electrically. Be careful of the package (looks like a "D" package to me). "N" or "P" or "DBR" has a different footprint. Your replacement chip will have a different datecode - not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The part you want is a SN74LS00DG4 -- TI uses the marking "LS00" without the 74 for the part number on those parts, as depicted on PDF page 9 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf).  The first line of markings is a date/manufacturing plant traceability code, save for the underlined G4, which is an affix used to indicate certain RoHS ("green") flows in the TI part numbering system.  It'll be different for your part (say 15xxxxx or 16xxxxx for a 2015 or 2016 part instead of 89xxxxx for a 1989 part).